# Side effects, short circuiting, and null propagating method call operator (?.)

Tags: c#, short-circuiting, side-effects, null-propagation-operator

When the target object is null in a conditional member access / null-propagating operator, and the member is a method, are arguments of the method evaluated?

That is, in the following code, is `g()` called?

```
SomeClass x = null;
x?.Foo(g());
```

How about `h()` in:

```
SomeClass x = null;
x?.Bar($"h = {h()}");
```

SharpLab puts the argument evaluation inside the `if` block, so it will be skipped.  But is this guaranteed by the specification or an implementation detail?

Comment: You can just run the code that you've already written and figure out real quick if the method is actually called.  If you want to know what the specifications say on the subject then *read the specifications*.

Comment: Why not try it out yourself?

Comment: `But is this guaranteed by the specification or an implementation detail?` (In addition to HimBromBeere's answer) Look up the C# 6.0 spec draft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#null-conditional-operator  What you look for is towards the end of the section "Null-conditional operator".

Comment: @Servy: I DID run the code, that led to the last paragraph.

Comment: @Servy: Also, I'm not sure where to find a specification that includes the latest C# versions, there's none installed with Visual Studio the way older specifications have been... the documentation I did find was lacking in specificity and didn't say what happens with arguments.

Comment: @elgonzo: Thanks, that could be turned into a great answer (by explaining exactly what happens to the argument lists, which appear in the grammar productions but nowhere in the semantic explanation).  The "textual replacement" rule seems like it does indicate the expected behavior.  It's not very satisfying to define things using text substitutions, but C# has done that before (e.g. transforming LINQ into sequences of method calls and lambdas)

Comment: @Servy: I'm glad engonzo provided a link to the right paragraph of the specification, because the specification's own Table of Contents doesn't have one, and I would never think to look for null-propagating member access, which absolutely is a binary operator, inside the section on unary operators.

Answer (score 3):

Although you could easily have tried out if or if not `g` is executed, here is the explanation why. The [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) is just a shortcut for a simple `null`check:

> "[The null-conditional operator]Tests the value of the left-hand
>   operand for `null` before performing a member access (`?.`) or index (`?[]`)
>   operation; returns `null` if the left-hand operand evaluates to `null`."

Thus your code is equivalent to the following:

```
if(x != null)
{
    x.Foo(g());
}
```

Comment: A test does not tell you what the language guarantees, just how the current implementation (you are testing) with the current JIT compiler (you are testing) handles this case. I wouldn't recommend testing as a solution for anything that might need to be portable across OS or .Net Framework versions.

Comment: @NetMage True, but the question actually consists of two parts: *what* happens and *why* it happens. The first could easily be determined by a test - which isn´t really covered by my answer. My answer on the other hand mainly handles the second point.

Comment: Actually I think neither are effectively answered, since you have no way to tell if .Net Core on Linux (or even C# on .Net 4.7.2 on Windows) is actually equivalent to your sample code without referring to the standard.

Comment: Evaluating the arguments is not part of the member access, so knowing that the member access is not performed tells us nothing about argument side-effects.  And you should try reading the entire question where I said what behavior I observed, instead of telling me how easy it is to try it.

Comment: 'Thus your code is equivalent to the following' *except that x is evaluated only once*, as the spec mentions multiple times.